# Are 11 outlets on a 15 amp breaker too many?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I have a 11 outlets on a 15amp breaker and second from the last on that circuit is gfci plug in the bathroom with one plug after it in a closet. Is this to much for that breaker?

Comment: I have a bank account with $1800 in it.  I need to write 11 checks.  Do I have enough money?    *That's not enough information Harper, I need to know what the amounts of the checks are.*   Likewise with you.  On a 15A breaker you have a budget of 1800VA.  (120V x 15A).  And each of your 11 plugs, there's an appliance which will draw a certain number of VA.  Like 12 for an iPad charger and 1500 for a heater.  What are you plugging in and what are the VA numbers on it?

Answer (score 0):

probably not, but there are a few other things wrong too.

Pretty sure that the bathroom outlet needs to be a 20amp (with 12 gauge wire) on a separate dedicated circuit.  think about this if you plugged in a 1800 Watt hairdryer you are maxxing the line and then you still have 10 other devices :) 
Also, the circuit from the bathroom should not lead outside i think with the exception directly to another bathroom outlet.

Whoever wired it up clearly missed a few points there and probably more -

ideally you want your circuit to serve a purpose whether it is lighting, or a room or some critical service.

Comment: I never goes outside

Comment: They make a hairdryer that pulls 1800 that is one bad ass mother

Comment: But I understand what your saying thanks

Comment: Depending on when the home was built creates the bathroom requirement it may not have even required gfci's and code dosent require old wiring to be changed unless remodeled even then old knob and tube is allowed to still be used within code.

Comment: wouldn't such a hair dryer have a special 20 amp plug? I've never seen one.

Comment: @agentp  Quick look on Amzn shows the 1800-watt or 1875-watt models are popular in professional-quality hair dryers. They have ordinary 15-A plugs on them, often with integral GFCI.  Even the "2000-watt" models have 15-A plugs.

Comment: I just put in 12-2 wire to two plugs in the bathroom on a 20 amp breaker and one of the plugs is a gfci so that should be just fine just seemed like over kill but I'm glad to have you guys to back my questions up

Comment: It's likely the house is grandfathered. When they change code, they don't make everyone change their wiring.